# How to check if package is installed by using unless?

Tags: azure, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I've created a puppet script to install Azure client and in the last step before using yum install, I want to make sure that the package haven't installed before for prevent from duplicate install.

My concept is
Execute the script if the output from az --help give nothing (which mean there's no Azure install)

or if you guys have any better choices please guide me, thanks!

And my code is

```
#install azure client
        exec { 'install-azure':
        command         => '/bin/yum install azure-cli -y',
        path            => '/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:',
        unless          => 'az --help',
        #require         => Exec['yumrepolist']
        }
```

It seems like there're something wrong with the code, I've checked a particular agent by using

```
puppet agent -t
```

> Notice:
>   /Stage[main]/Os_preparation::Azure_install/Exec[yumrepolist]/returns:
>   executed successfully Error:
>   /Stage[main]/Os_preparation::Azure_install/Exec[install-azure]: Could
>   not evaluate: Could not find command 'az'

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a `Package` resource for this? You seem to be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: actually, i'm not sure whether exec or package should use. Since It comes with yum install.

Comment: I don't follow.  If you have in mind to install it via `yum`, then why would it *not* be appropriate to manage it via a `Package` resource?

Answer (score 1):

You should install `azure-cli` using a `package` resource. Also, you should add its Yum repository as a `yumrepo` resource.

Try something like the following, which replicates the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-yum?view=azure-cli-latest.

```
yumrepo { 'azure-cli':
  descr    => 'Azure CLI',
  baseurl  => 'https://packages.microsoft.com/yumrepos/azure-cli',
  enabled  => 1,
  gpgcheck => 1,
  gpgkey   => 'https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc',
}

package { 'azure-cli':
  ensure  => installed,
  require => Yumrepo['azure-cli'],
}
```